# using highchart in mobile when legends click toggling chart not coming properly in ui. can some please help me

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8i0b.png)enter image description here

> *can you check image url once*

I am using high chart version [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaQ6l.png)7.2.2 using below code.

```
enter code here
```

1. `List item`

   .highcharts-figure,
   .highcharts-data-table table {
     min-width: 310px;
     max-width: 800px;
     margin: 1em auto;
   }

   #container {
   width: 650px;
   height: 650px;
   }

   .highcharts-data-table table {
   font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
   margin: 10px auto;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 500px;
   }

   .highcharts-data-table caption {
   padding: 1em 0;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   color: #555;
   }

   .highcharts-data-table th {
   font-weight: 600;
   padding: 0.5em;
   }

   .highcharts-data-table td,
   .highcharts-data-table th,
   .highcharts-data-table caption {
   padding: 0.5em;
   }

   .highcharts-data-table thead tr,
   .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
   background: #f8f8f8;
   }

   .highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
   background: #f1f7ff;
   }

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   Highcharts.chart('container',{
    chart: {

   },
   "credits": {
     "enabled": false
   },
   "exporting": {
     "enabled": false
   },
   "legend": {
    // "enabled": true,
     "squareSymbol": false,
     "symbolHeight": 15,
     "symbolRadius": 2,
     "symbolWidth": 20
   },
   "plotOptions": {
     "line": {
       "marker": {
         "enabled": false
       },

     },
     series: {
       events: {
         legendItemClick: function(event) {
                        console.log('legendItemClick');
                   },
                   click: function(event) {
                       console.log('click');
                   },
         mouseOver: function () {
                  return false;
               },
               mouseOut: function () {
                   return false;
               }
       }
     }
   },
   "series": [
     {
       "id": "2019",
       "name": "2019",
       "type": "column",
       "data": [
         [
           0,
           0
         ],
         [
           1,
           0
         ],
         [
           2,
           0
         ],
         [
           3,
           0
         ],
         [
           4,
           0
         ],
         [
           5,
           0
         ],
         [
           6,
           0
         ],
         [
           7,
           0
         ],
         [
           8,
           0
         ],
         [
           9,
           4000
         ],
         [
           10,
           5000
         ],
         [
           11,
           4000
         ]
       ],
       "color": {
         "linearGradient": {
           "y1": 0,
           "x1": 0,
           "y2": 1,
           "x2": 0
         },
         "stops": [
           [
             0,
             "#BAEAFF"
           ],
           [
             1,
             "#009BDE"
           ]
         ]
       }
     },
     {
       "id": "2020",
       "name": "2020",
       "type": "column",
       "data": [
         [
           0,
           5000
         ],
         [
           1,
           5000
         ],
         [
           2,
           4000
         ],
         [
           3,
           6000
         ],
         [
           4,
           6000
         ],
         [
           5,
           5000
         ],
         [
           6,
           5000
         ],
         [
           7,
           4000
         ],
         [
           8,
           5000
         ],
         [
           9,
           38000
         ],
         [
           10,
           6000
         ],
         [
           11,
           5000
         ]
       ],
       "color": {
         "linearGradient": {
           "y1": 0,
           "x1": 0,
           "y2": 1,
           "x2": 0
         },
         "stops": [
           [
             0,
             "#FF246B"
           ],
           [
             1,
             "#AD083E"
           ]
         ]
       }
     },
     {
       "id": "2021",
       "name": "2021",
       "type": "column",
       "data": [
         [
           0,
           7000
         ],
         [
           1,
           6000
         ],
         [
           2,
           4000
         ],
         [
           3,
           7000
         ],
         [
           4,
           4000
         ],
         [
           5,
           5000
         ],
         [
           6,
           0
         ],
         [
           7,
           0
         ],
         [
           8,
           0
         ],
         [
           9,
           0
         ],
         [
           10,
           0
         ],
         [
           11,
           0
         ]
       ],
       "color": {
         "linearGradient": {
           "y1": 0,
           "x1": 0,
           "y2": 1,
           "x2": 0
         },
         "stops": [
           [
             0,
             "#44A5FA"
           ],
           [
             1,
             "#276092"
           ]
         ]
       }
     },
     {
       "id": "linearAxis",
       "name": "Neighborhood",
       "type": "line",
       "data": [
         [
           "Jan",
           136
         ],
         [
           "Feb",
           126
         ],
         [
           "Mar",
           120
         ],
         [
           "Apr",
           137
         ],
         [
           "May",
           130
         ],
         [
           "Jun",
           146
         ],
         [
           "Jul",
           82
         ],
         [
           "Aug",
           77
         ],
         [
           "Sep",
           79
         ],
         [
           "Oct",
           146
         ],
         [
           "Nov",
           145
         ],
         [
           "Dec",
           125
         ]
       ],
       "color": "#52CE4D"
     }
   ],
   "time": {
     "useUTC": false
   },
   "tooltip": {
     "enabled": true,
     "shared": true
   },
   "title": {
     "text": ""
   },
   "lang": {},
   "xAxis": {
     "title": {
       "enabled": false
     },
     "tickWidth": 1,
     "arrow": false,
     "reversed": false,
     "categories": [
       "Jan",
       "Feb",
       "Mar",
       "Apr",
       "May",
       "Jun",
       "Jul",
       "Aug",
       "Sep",
       "Oct",
       "Nov",
       "Dec"
     ],
     "type": "category"
   },
   "yAxis": [
     {
       "title": {
         "text": "thousands"
       },
       "tickWidth": 1,
       "arrow": false,
       "reversed": false,
       "type": "linear"
     }
   ]
   ```

   });

   ```
   </script>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take your time and format the question so it can we can read it easy. Question that is formatted like this has a high chance of getting closed without being answered.

Comment: Hi @mahesh p.v, Please provide a more detailed description of the problem.